# Terminology on generics types

Tags: c#, java, c++, generics

When I read about generic programming, often, are used this two terms:

1. parametrized types;
2. type parameters

Are there difference between them?

Comment: Yes, depending on the programming language.

Comment: Choose one language please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, in the following declaration

```
public class Foo<T> { ... }
```

`Foo` is a [parameterized type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). `T` is a type parameter.

Comment: Is also an instance creation (i.e. Foo<Integer> f = new Foo<>();) a parametrized type?

Comment: @xdevel2000 Generics in Java are a compile time concept (think of type erasure). When we speak of types, we mean array, class, interface, or enum types. So an instance is not a type of any sort. In your comment's code snippet, the `<Integer>` part is a type _argument_, `Foo` is a _parameterized type_.

Answer (score 3):

Using C++ terminology:

A class template corresponds to a parameterised type - it becomes a type once you specify arguments for the parameters.

A type parameter is a parameter of a template, for which the arguments are types.

Answer (score 2):

Generic types are also known as parametized types.

Type parameters refers to the types associated with a generic type. For example, with

```
Dictionary<T1, T2>
```

T1 and T2 are the type parameters.